# Why doesn't the Collections method 'contains' work if the collection has relations?

Tags: laravel, collections, contains

For example:

```
$users = User::all();

$user = User::find(1)->get();

$sameUser = User::find(1)->with('roles')->get();

$user->is($sameUser) // true

$users->contains($user) // true

$users->contains($sameUser) // false
```

Shouldn't it return true for all three checks?

Answer (score 0):

It's not that it isn't working with the relationship but you're messing things up with the `get()` calls.  `find()` returns the instance of the user and actually calls `User::where('id', '=', $id)->first();` under the hood so all of the following will return true:

```
$users = User::all();

$user = User::find(1);

$sameUser = User::with('roles')->find(1);

$user->is($sameUser) 

$users->contains($user)

$users->contains($sameUser)
```

Comment: Nah it still returns false, the query isn't the problem: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18902

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/18902

> technically the objects are not the same if one has eager loaded
>   relationships, and the other doesn't. while they may represent the
>   same row in the database, PHP has no way of knowing that.
>
> in this situation you may have do it based on your primary keys.